# LWJGL - following a tutorial, yet I get a bug about native code

Tags: java, lwjgl

So I am following a tutorial in youtube about LWJGL by ThinMatrix. 
I checked a few times if my code is any different than his and didn't find anything different. I tried to look up for an answer and yet - nothing.

The error I receive is this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000052a0ab79, pid=7072, tid=0x0000000000001a9c
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.DLL+0x142ab79]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\MY Games\Games\ThinMatrixTutorial-To Be Game Engine\hs_err_pid7072.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I have tried to fix it and found out that I have a problem in my renderer, how ever I have no pre-compilation errors nor run time errors.

```
    package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Renderer {

    public void prepare() {
        GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void render(RawModel model) {
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVertexCount());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I tried some of the solutions here and none worked. So I tried to change some code and the order of the calls in my main method and I fixed it. Thanks though for those who tried to help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure

> ```
>     GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVertexCount());
> ```
>
> should not take a vertex count, but the id of a vertex array, which was returned by a create-method earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what was reported in `hs_err_pid7072.log` the most likely culprits are:

- Missing OpenGL drivers for your video card.
- Older video drivers.
- Using 32-bit LWJGL/drivers with a 64-bit JVM, or *vise versa*.
- Using a graphics feature that your video card does not support.